# Java RTP/HTTP Streaming

Tags: java, http, streaming, rtp, xuggle

i'm decoding and encoding a videofile via Xuggle to FLV-video format and send it via Sockets to my java server (not the entire file, only parts of it every X seconds). On the server-side I get the encoded file as ByteArrayInputStream. Is it possible to stream this ByteArrayInputStream via rtp or http-streaming? Or do i need a finished encoded file for that? I'm creating a video streaming server, where the client encodes the video file and sends it to the server in parts. This is already done. I'm now stuck on the server side, to stream the ByteArrayInputStream via RTP or HTTP, so I can watch it via VLC. Are there any good examples for it?

I've already tested to save the ByteArrayInputStream to file. This works but I don't wanna save the file on the server. I wanna stream it ;)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1) See Server implementation
http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp3310/2004/Labs/lab6/lab5.html

2) http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/ and see http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/Streaming